# updating iOS app when safari is disabled

Tags: ios, safari

On a restricted (safari is disabled) iOS device, there is a way to update an app from appstore, i have been searching for this, but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating an App you do not need Safari. You update an App from App Store.